# verfiy my proof (Prove that for all sets A, B, C, $(A \cup B)-C = (A-C) \cup (B-C)$)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Prove that for all sets A, B, C, $(A \cup B)-C = (A-C) \cup (B-C)$

suppose $x \in A,B,C$

if $x\in A$ or $B$ or both , then by definition of union, $x\in A\cup B$.

Since $x\in (A \cup B) $ and $x\in C$, by definition of subtraction, $x\notin (A \cup B)-C$

Since $x \in A$ and $x \in C$, by definition of subtraction, $x \notin (A-C)$, the same is true if $x \in B$, then $x \notin (B-C)$.

Now if $x \notin (A-C)$ and $x \notin (B-C)$ then $x \notin (A-C) \cup (B-C)$ and $x \notin (A \cup B) -C$

thus $(A \cup B)-C = (A-C)\cup (B-C)$

verify my proof?

-thanks

Comment: Small typo: on the fifth line I think you meant to say $x\not\in (A - C)$.

Comment: @SpiralRain ah yes thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit confusing because you start by assuming "$x\in A,B,C$", but what does that mean? Are we assuming $x\in A\cap B\cap C$? If so, you should say that.

It's also not clear how it benefits us to assume that $x$ is in that intersection. There are precisely two things we need to show: (1) That every $x$ that's an element of the left-hand-side is also an element of the right-hand-side, and (2) That every $x$ that's an element of the right-hand-side is also an element of the left-hand-side. That's our way to show set equality.

Therefore, our first step should be to assume that $x$ is on one side or the other, and then prove that it's on the other side as well.

I'll show you one direction:

> Suppose $x\in (A\cup B)-C$. Then $x\in A\cup B$ but $x\not\in C$. We have two cases (a) suppose $x\in A$. Then we have $x\in A-C$. (b) suppose $x\not\in A$, then $x\in B$. Thus, $x\in B-C$. In either case, we have $x\in(A-C)\cup(B-C)$.
>
> We conclude: $(A\cup B)-C \subseteq (A-C)\cup(B-C)$

Do you see how I started with $x$ an element of the LHS, and ended up showing that the same $x$ must be an element of the RHS? Try and write the other direction, where you start with something in $(A-C)\cup(B-C)$, and show that it must also be in $(A\cup B)-C$.

Comment: ok thanks ill go back and have another shot at it

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might be useful to comment on the proof a little more. I don't think you even proved what you wanted to prove at all!

I'll write the left-hand side set as $L = (A\cup B) - C$ and the right-hand side set as $R = (A - C)\cup (B - C)$.

You showed that if $x\in A, B, C$, then $x\not\in L, R$. That's something, but that's not enough to conclude that $L = R$. 
What if we have $x\in R$ but $x\not\in L$? Your proof doesn't really eliminate that possibility.

The safest approach to doing these proofs is to stick with the definitions. The way I define equality between sets is that I say two sets are equal whenever $x\in L$ if and only if $x\in R$.

This means there are two parts: (1) I want to suppose $x\in L$ and then show that this implies $x\in R$, and then (2) I want to suppose $x\in R$ and show that this implies $x\in L$. Once you do that you have that $x\in L$ if and only if $x\in R$, and thus $L = R$ by definition.

Answer (score 1):

after rethinking my proof i came up with:

suppose $x \in (A \cup B) -C$

if $x \in (A \cup B)-c $ then $x \notin C$ this $x \in A$ and/or $x\in B$

Since $x \notin C$ and $x\in (A \cup B)-C$ , $x \in (A-C)$ and/or $x \in (B-C)$

thus if $x \in (A-C)$ and/or $x \in (B-C)$ then $x \in (A-C) \cup (B-C)$

by the definition of union, the same result occurs if x is in only one of both A and B.

Hence, $(A\cup B) - C = (A-C)\cup (B-C)$

Comment: @SpiralRain is this looking better?

Comment: Yeah, it looks better. That's roughly what you want. You showed that if $x\in (A\cup B) - C$ then $x\in (A - C)\cup (B - C)$.

Comment: However, that's only the first part of the proof. You also want to show the opposite: if $x\in (A - C)\cup (B - C)$ then show that $x\in (A\cup B) - C$. It shouldn't be that much harder.